# Rails + Cucumber: How do I delete the session but keep the cookies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

How do I delete the session but keep the cookies? I'm trying to simulate a browser close/reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your step definitions you can access the session directly and remove any/all of your critical values.  Assuming that you're trying to test login/logout you could remove the `user_id` value from the session.

```
session[:user_id] = nil
```